# QList: Out of memory

Tags: qt, out-of-memory, qlist

I have a graphical application written in Qt for embedded linux. Part of this application is to update a display screen every 250 ms. However, after about 8-10 hours the application crashes with a "QList: Out of memory" error. I've isolated the function and the lines (in a sense) where it happens, but I have no idea why it happens since I'm not using QList. The only active lines of code in this function are at the end of this question.

I realize that QList doesn't ever 'shrink' the memory it uses to hold items, but I'm not using QList anywhere in my code. I'm only calling 'setStyleSheet' to set various fonts and properties on ui widgets (labels, text fields, etc) There's more code, but its all commented out so I'm assuming it has something to do with setStyleSheet. Does anyone know why this is happening? If so, do you know of a way around this? I'm using Q.t. 4.3 btw (due to it being specifically loaded on the embedded system I'm using).

Thanks a lot for your time.

```
if(twc_rx){
        ui->label_Rx->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: lime; font: bold 16px 'Arial' }");
  }else if(!twc_rx){
    ui->label_Rx->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: grey; font: bold 16px 'Arial' }");

  }//line 561 to 684
  if(twc_tx){
   ui->label_Tx->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: lime; font: bold 16px 'Arial' }");
  }else{
   ui->label_Tx->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: grey; font: bold 16px 'Arial' }");
  }if(ats_stat){
       ui->label_ATS->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: lime; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");
  }else{
       ui->label_ATS->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: red; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");
  }
  if(atp_stat){
       ui->label_atp2->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: lime; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");
  }else{
       ui->label_atp2->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: red; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");
  }
  if(ato_stat){
       ui->label_ATO->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: lime; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");

  }else{
       ui->label_ATO->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: red; border-radius: 10; font: bold 16px 'Arial'}");
  }
```

EDIT:

I should mention that these lines are being executed every 250 ms based on an input message from another subsystem. I've already went down that road and its a dead end. This is the error code.

Comment: Probably you forget to free memory and have memory leak. Use [valgrind](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_valgrind_with_Qt_Creator) to detect it

Comment: Problem is this: when these lines (or similar lines) are commented out there is no error and no memory leak. I do not use QList anywhere else in my code except one other place that is stack-allocated and not being refreshed every 250 ms (so no way it grows to the limit).

Comment: What happens if you set the stylesheet to empty strings?

Comment: I'll test that. It usually takes 10 hours or so to fail so I'll have to get back to this thread tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using qstylesheets is more for static properties.  If you intend to change properties on the fly, I would look into [Customizing Using Dynamic Properties](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties).

> ### Customizing Using Dynamic Properties
>
> There are many situations where we need to present a form that has
>   mandatory fields. To indicate to the user that the field is mandatory,
>   one effective (albeit esthetically dubious) solution is to use yellow
>   as the background color for those fields. It turns out this is very
>   easy to implement using Qt Style Sheets. First, we would use the
>   following application-wide style sheet:
>
> ```
>  *[mandatoryField="true"] { background-color: yellow }
> ```
>
> This means that every widget whose mandatoryField Qt property is set
>   to true would have a yellow background.
>
> Then, for each mandatory field widget, we would simply create a
>   mandatoryField property on the fly and set it to true. For example:
>
> ```
>  QLineEdit *nameEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
>  nameEdit->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);
>
>  QLineEdit *emailEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
>  emailEdit->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);
>
>  QSpinBox *ageSpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
>  ageSpinBox->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);
> ```

It appears to be more friendly for swapping values frequently.  This is explained well for Qt 4.7, but it appears to still be available in Qt 4.3: [The Style Sheet Syntax: Selector Types](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)

So basically, instead of adding to the list of q stylesheets set for your app over and over again, you should make some of the styles dependent on a property, and set that property, then unset the stylesheet and then re-set it.  I believe this can be done with the [`unpolish`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/qstyle.html#unpolish) and [`polish`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/qstyle.html#polish) commands (see [Styles and Style Aware Widgets](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/style-reference.html)).

EDIT: Below is an example of using this technique.  There is a mainwindow.ui with a QPushButton on it.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimerEvent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString stylesheet =
            "*[mandatoryField=\"true\"] { background-color: yellow }"
            "*[mandatoryField=\"false\"] { background-color: gray }"
            "QPushButton[otherField=\"true\"] { border: none; }"
            "QPushButton[otherField=\"false\"] { border-color: navy; }";
    ui->pushButton->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);
    ui->pushButton->setProperty("otherField", true);
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);

    this->startTimer(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    static int count = 0;

    if(count % 2)
    {
        bool previousMandatoryFieldValue = ui->pushButton->property("mandatoryField").toBool();
        ui->pushButton->setProperty("mandatoryField", !previousMandatoryFieldValue);
        qDebug() << "mf" << previousMandatoryFieldValue;
    }
    else
    {
        bool previousOtherFieldValue = ui->pushButton->property("otherField").toBool();
        ui->pushButton->setProperty("otherField", !previousOtherFieldValue);
        qDebug() << "of" << previousOtherFieldValue;
    }
    ui->pushButton->style()->unpolish(ui->pushButton);
    ui->pushButton->style()->polish(ui->pushButton);

    this->update();

    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I will try this out and see if it works. Though I wonder why the QList memory error happened, if this fixes it no worries!

Comment: I just noticed this: 
"So basically, instead of adding to the list of q stylesheets set for your app over and over again"

So you're saying that the call 'setStyleSheet' doesn't 'set the stylesheet' it just adds to a list of stylesheets???

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the implementation of it, but there are a bunch of rules for conflict resolution with cascading stylesheets.  I think it does keep all of them in a big list and when resolving a style, iterates through the list, and finds the one that applies for the widget.

Comment: Ok having a problem here, when I set the stylesheet dynamically of a ui->label in the constructor, and then set the property defined in that style sheet to the proper value IN THE CONSTRUCTOR it works, and I can change the value/color on the fly based on this. But when I set the property in a function outside of the constructor nothing happens. 

So I'm assuming its a scope issue. How do I globalize the scope? I'm assuming I'd have to use the Q_PROPERTY macro, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that with ui-> elements. The documentation on this is kinda spotty 'm afraid.

Comment: Did you use "unpolish" and "polish"?  Are you using [setProperty](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/qobject.html#setProperty)?  The first time you use it on a QObject it will create the property if it doesn't exist and the second time it will just modify the property.  You shouldn't need to use the Q_PROPERTY macro, just use setProperty().

Comment: I create the property like this setStyleSheet("*[opmode=\'A\'] { background-color: lime } then I set ui->label_ats->setProperty("opmode","A"); And that sets the color properly BUT ONLY IN THE CONSTRUCTOR. When I attempt to do this in a different function (with setproperty, unpolish/polish etc) it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks alot for that example it really helped. For some reason I thought I could get away with using style()-> as opposed to ui->label_auto->style()->.  Go figure. Thanks alot man!