# Marking a widget as unselected when another widget is clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a [flowlayout](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/layouts-flowlayout.html) that shows movie thumbnails (subclassed qwidgets). When I click a thumbnail, it's marked as selected by setting a stylesheet to it (css border). What I want to do is, if I 1) click another thumbnail, or 2) click the widget that holds the flowlayout, it should be marked as unselected.

I've currently implemented the mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) method to draw the border when the thumbnail is clicked. I'm not sure how to proceed with marking it as unselected. Thanks.

Comment: You could make the thumbnails QAbstractButton subclasses and put them into a QButtonGroup with setExclusive(true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store link to currently selected widget somewhere and unselect it when selecting some other.
Something like this:

```
someClass::someClass():
activeWidget(0)
{
    for(......)
    {
        subclassedQWidget *w = new subclassedQWidget(this);
        // ......
        // ......
        QObject::connect(w, SIGNAL(iAmClicked()), this, SLOT(someoneClicked()))
    }

}

someClass::someoneClicked()
{
    subclassedQWidget *caller = (subclassedQWidget*)QObject::sender();
    if (caller == activeWidget) {return;} //Do nothing when active widget clicked
    if (activeWidget) activeWidget->unSelect();
    if (caller)
    {
        caller->select();
        activeWidget = caller;
    }
}
```

in `mousePressEvent` in Your `subclassedQWidget` You simply `emit iAmClicked()`

Answer (score 2):

A way that I have done such a thing in the past, is to make a signal in the button class that signals all the other buttons to go unselected.

So the widget that has a pointer to all the objects makes the connection between the signal of one to one of its signals, and its signal to deselect the object.

Here are some skeleton classes of what you would need.

```
class Button
{
signals:
    void selected(Button *);
slot:
    void deselect(Button *);
}

class ButtonContainer
{
public:
    void addButton(Button *)
signals:
    void buttonSelected(Button *);
}
```

When adding a button connect it to the container this way:

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(selected(Button *)), 
                 buttonContainer, SIGNAL(buttonSelected(Button *)));
QObject::connect(buttonContainer, SIGNAL(buttonSelected(Button *)), 
                 button, SLOT(deselect(Button *)));
```

When the mouse press event happens, emit this signal after applying your "selected" stylesheet:

```
emit selected(this);
```

In the deselect slot put this:

```
void Button::deselect(Button * selectedButton)
{
    if(this != selectedButton)
    {
        // apply stylesheet for deselecting if it was previously selected
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

By the way, be sure to make sure that you aren't setting  the stylesheet too often.  I haven't done extensive testing, but in at least some versions of Qt, it could go past the limit of QList.  They have dynamic properties available to do frequent style changes:

[QList: Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564823/qlist-out-of-memory/13568733#13568733)

Comment: I don't want to start some flame discussion, but isn't it a waste of rosources, when You call deselect() of, say, 100 other buttons?

Comment: That's a good point.  Probably using this similar setup, you could just disconnect and connect the buttons to the buttonContainer's signal when it gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with a polygon of points.  When a person selects a point in my polygon, I color it green and deselect previous point (unless they hold ctrl).

To achieve this, I have a managing QGraphicsItem which holds my polygon and all of its points.  On click event it determines which point was selected and determines whether to deselect or add to selection.

For your implementation, perhaps a managing QWidget class which holds all of these thumbnails and intercepts all click events before passing them on to the correct sub widget.