# Using the value of an existing style sheet element as the value of another

Tags: qt, styling

I am attempting to set the style sheets on my `QTreeView` such that the selected item has the same colour regardless of whether or not the view has focus. I'm doing it using

```
QTreeView::item:selected:!active { 
    background: myColour; 
}
```

Instead of passing a hard-coded value into my style sheet, I'd like to use the value of `QTreeView::item:selected:active`, allowing me to always have the colour set correctly. I had a quick go at this with

```
QTreeView::item:selected:!active { 
    background: QTreeView::item:selected:active; 
}
```

just to see what happened, which was nothing. How can I extract the value of `QTreeView::item:selected:active` and use it in my style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the background color for the active color group out of the Palette and apply it to the widget's palette.

[`QWidget::palette()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#palette-prop)

[`QPalette`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QPalette.html)

[`QPalette::color()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#color)

[`QPalette::ColorRole`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum)

[`QPalette::ColorGroup`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum)

So this is what the code would look like somewhere after you have applied/polished your stylesheet for your `QTreeViewItem`.

```
QPalette modifiedPalette(this->palette());
QColor activeBgColor(this->palette().color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Window));
modifiedPalette.setColor(QPalette::Window, activeBgColor);

this->setPalette(modifiedPalette);
```

Hope that helps.

---

Two other options you could also explore include:

Using dynamic properties, or basically tying some property you control to styling.  I made a longer post explaining it to someone recently:

[QList: Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564823/qlist-out-of-memory/13568733#13568733)

Or you could parse the information out of the `QString` returned by `stylesheet()` using a regular expression of some sort and store it somewhere, but this could be problematic if the stylesheet for that widget doesn't have it , and it is referencing a parent's stylesheet.  You might also look into using the style property of QWidget, too.

[`QWidget::styleSheet()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)