# Colouring a button in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to design a simple button (QPushButton or QToolButton, either can work) that would essentially be a rectangle of the colour it represents. Clicking it opens a QColorDialog, and selecting a colour in it repaints the button.

So, basically, something that will look like one of these:

[image]

I made a few attempts, none of which brought me the functionality I wanted.

Slot:

```cpp
void MainWindow::OnButtonColorClick()
{
    QColor initialColor = ui->buttonColor->palette().color(QPalette::Background);

    QColor colorSelected = QColorDialog::getColor(initialColor, this);

    if(colorSelected.isValid())
    {
        ui->buttonColor->setPalette(QPalette(colorSelected));
        ui->buttonColor->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    }
}
```

---

Attempt #1:

Set the Palette in the constructor:

```cpp
ui->buttonCoulor->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::black));
```

Result: ordinary button before click, thin coloured contour after selection.

[image]

---

Attempt #2:

Add stylesheet:

```
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Result: black rectangle before click, black rectangle after selection.

[image]

---

I feel like I'm circling the drain. Essentially, how do I achieve:

[image]

?

Comment: can you reset the stylesheet using setStyleSheet?

Comment: @MinLin I thought about that. I find it a bit tedious to construct the stylesheet just for that. I'd do it if it was the only way, but I'm wondering if there isn't something more... natural? Maybe a different control altogether...

Comment: @MinLin I'm not judging, if that's the way Qt is managed, so be it. I'm just curious.

Comment: I remember that when a button is drawn, there are several steps, but I don't remember that, Let's check the code

Comment: Look at this http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-6707.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish the desired effect:

```
// Slot for the button
void MainWindow::on_button()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor();

    QString s("background: #"
                          + QString(color.red() < 16? "0" : "") + QString::number(color.red(),16)
                          + QString(color.green() < 16? "0" : "") + QString::number(color.green(),16)
                          + QString(color.blue() < 16? "0" : "") + QString::number(color.blue(),16) + ";");
    button->setStyleSheet(s);
    button->update();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I my several attempts I might have done something similar, but forgot to call `button->update()`. This works, and might reconciliate me with stylesheets.

Comment: There is also `polish()` and `unpolish()` in QStyle, that can effectly do the same thing.  Here is a related post where I worked with dynamic properties to get the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564823/qlist-out-of-memory/13568733#13568733

Answer (score 1):

use setStyleSheet with this style sheet:

```
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #XXXXXX;
```

where XXXXXX is the value returned by `QString::number(myColor.rgb(), 16).toUpper();`

No need to set any other properties on the button. Leave them all as default and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working just fine for me:

```
if(colorSelected.isValid())
{
    ui->buttonColor->setPalette(QPalette(colorSelected));
}
```

Comment: There must be a delta somewhere, I had that (attempt #1) and got the image I showed above.

Comment: I would remove the setAutoFillBackground(true);

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to phyatt's answer, there's a shortcut to generate the XML-formatted color string:

```
QString s("background: " + color.name + ";");
button->setStyleSheet(s);
```