# QT Creator and documentation popup

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm asking you this because i couldn't find any answer. The closest one is this:

[Using automatic documentation of my own function with Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955686/using-automatic-documentation-of-my-own-function-with-qt-creator)

but it's for qt creator 2.4 while now we are at 3.1, so i hope things changed. I'd like to have something similar to Visual Studio XML documentation for Intellisense.

I mean that before one function i add a description of its content and the params and qt creator pops up that info when i type that function's name.

Is this possible? I always find something about doxygen, but it's for HTML or LaTeX documentation, not for the "popup" documentation.

Thank you for your time