# Qt style sheets are not applied immediately

Tags: css, qt

I have a console window in my Qt application whose output window is a specialised *QTextEdit*, outputting messages that are processed after a command is parsed from a *QLineEdit* and subsequently executed by the main program. The window can output normal messages, warnings and, if desired, text in a number of 6 different custom colours. All 8 different types of text have their colour defined by 8 different *QProperties* of type *QColor;* these are set, along with the rest of the output window's styling, through the use of a QSS file applied to the *QApplication* when it loads. To write text in a certain colour, *setTextColor* is called on the *QTextEdit* just before inserting the text. (As an aside, *moveCursor* when called on the *QTextEdit* appears to reset the colour of the text to be inserted to the default colour regardless of what it was set to before, but I've made sure to set the desired text colour immediately after calling *moveCursor* and before calling *insertPlainText.*)

The problem I am having is that it appears (as far as I can see) that the styling applied through *qApp->setStyleSheet* is not actually applied until the message queue is processed. When the program starts it applies the style sheet and shortly afterwards a hard-coded test message is sent to the console window showing the date and time of the last compile. This message ends up being printed in the original *QTextEdit* colour (black), which is invisible after the black background colour in the style sheet is applied. The problem is not as simple as setting the standard text colour of the console window when the style is applied, as any number of messages could potentially be sent to the console window before the styling takes effect, resulting in any number of differently coloured messages.

I am trying to think of the best way to remedy this problem. The best way I can think of at the moment is a tagging method where messages would be enclosed in semantic tags (eg. all warning messages would be enclosed in HTML-like tags to specify that they are warnings), and when a console window's styling is applied each message would be re-coloured according to the new styling. This would obviously require hooking into some "OnStyleApplied" event for the *QTextEdit.* Would this be possible, or is there a better method to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is really applying the qstylesheet changes in the message queue, tell the message queue to get processed before your next call.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

You can even specify which class of events that should be processed.

The other way that should work, is you can specifically tell the widget to apply its style changes when you want it to.

I put together an in-depth look at some advanced stuff with qstylesheets the other day:

[QList: Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564823/qlist-out-of-memory/13568733#13568733)

Note the use of `polish` and `unpolish` in the link above.

But besides all of the direct answers, you may want to look into using the classes that are made for rich text editing:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/richtext.html

The structure is well thought out and you can do a lot with them.  There is a learning curve to figuring them out, but it works well.

This is kind of related to what you are talking about...

Also here is a neat tool that Qt has:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

When you combine that with `<some text editor/viewer class qt has>.append();`, then when you want to add text, you can just use the `qDebug() <<` call, and you get all the niceties of inserted spaces, newlines, and auto rendering of many Qt Classes debug string representations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: After some more testing, it appears that my problem might be to do with the test message being sent to the console window after it has physically been created (of course), but before exec() is called on the QApplication. However, if rich text looks like a better option then I might just go with that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has this problem, I found a solution - unpolish() and polish() on a widget cause any QProperties set via a style sheet to update properly, meaning their values in code are then current after calling the polish functions.